# Upcoming changes to Exchange Web Services (EWS) API for Office 365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

Currently we are using EWS API with basic authentication to automate CRUD activities for outlook tasks and calendar items. NOT outlook mail (sending/retrieving messages/mails etc.)

Looking at the notice where the basic authentication will stop working by October 2020, i have started to explore the alternative which is moving to Microsoft Graph API.

But i noticed, there is not yet CRUD for tasks and calendar items under **Outlook Mail**.

I found the below while googling but seems is not working.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

My question is, will the EWS with basic authentication affect the Outlook tasks and calendar events as well?

Why i don't see them in the Graph API explorer? they should be under Outlook Mail

I appreciate if you guys can give me insight

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

The authentication changes for EWS will impact all the API endpoints available under it on exchange online.
You can find documentation about CRUD operation for Outlook tasks [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/outlooktask?view=graph-rest-beta)
For the graph explorer make sure you click on "show more samples" in the bottom left corner to see everything.
For the events you have the right endpoint, you should switch to a get request to obtain them and check that you requested the proper permissions.